# Uploading packages through the Xbox One Windows Device Portal

Tags: windows, xbox-one

Currently, Microsoft offers a web portal to access certain components of the Xbox One. This is called the Windows Device Portal, and I am able to access this fine.

However, I am having serious issues with its capabilities. For one, there doesn't seem to be any way to deploy applications through the web portal. Is there a way, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, installing an Appx via Device Portal on Xbox is not possible.  However, the tool will be added back (and working) in the next build for retail kits.

Answer (score 0):

As of July 2016, the current version of the **Xbox One Developer Mode** does support installing apps through the [Device Portal web interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal).